# Login to Facebook on Android and getting an access token in return

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, token

Firstly I apologize if this is a question that has been asked many times.

There have been too many different versions of doing this (many of which include code that are deprecated).

I would like to know how to implement the following:

1. Facebook login prompt upon reaching an activity page
2. Upon successful login return the access token

I have already gotten an APP id and configured the secret key in Facebook.

I require the following permissions: ["email", "user_birthday", "publish_actions", "user_likes"]

One addition question! Is it possible to have a Facebook login prompt if the official Facebook app is not installed on the device?

Look forward to your advice, sample code templates or direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

You don't need facebook installed. A webview will be used if the the app isn't installed.